# Uninstalling a program misplaced in home folder

Tags: apt, package-management, software-uninstall

There is a program located in my home folder which apparently can't be found by apt nor dpkg. If I use `apt-cache policy *part-of-name*`, it would tell me the full name of the package but that it couldn't be found. Is there a way to uninstall it without apt or to make it find it?
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: How did you install it? Manually? Via `apt`? With `dpgk`? Self-compiled?

Answer (score 0):

`apt` will never place programs in your home directory, so you did that yourself.

It is preferred to use the uninstall procedure of the program, if provided. If that is not available, then you will need to just delete the installed program folders and files.